# What is the name of this Danish award-winning indie drama?

Tags: identify-this-movie

- **Media:** Movie (live-action, feature length)
- **Date of release/watch:** I watched it a couple of years ago, it's a guess but post-2000 seems safe (could be late 90s)
- **Plot summary:** A wealthy upper class family host a dinner-party in a giant mansion, much of the beginning of the movie is dedicated to how most of the characters really hate these family get-together parties. The party takes place over a few days and may be to celebrate the patron (rich grandfather, lord of the mansion) and his birthday. They have pleasant introductions but in time there are arguments and everything gets awkward. **The big reveal near the end is that the protagonist has had enough and confronts the father publicly and loudly at the dinner table about how he sexually abused him as a young child growing up, detailing it with agony**. This pulls a thread on the fabric of the family and it all becomes undone and collapses. I'm not certain, but it's possible the patron kills himself soon after. The movie is a commentary on how people will keep horrible things like this quiet and repressed for the sake of maintaining an illusion of family and tradition, because the alternative seems so much worse.
- **Setting:** Grand upper-class mansion, in the style of *Clue* or *Gosford Park*, or any of the classic 'Who dun it?' settings. This is very similar, except the big punch is a reveal rather than a murder.
- **Country:** Denmark (Danish language)
- **Additional info:**

  - **Distribution:** Indie (or at least looks very raw, rough, lower-quality camera)
  - **Length:** Between 90 mins and 2 hours
  - **Tech:** While it looked very low-quality (as if it were filmed on an old cameraphone), it was in colour
  - It won a bunch of film festival awards (Cannes Film Festival) and was lauded for being the first of its kind (I don't remember the exact style/genre they referred to)

Comment: Oh, I know this one! Give me an hour or so and I'll write up an answer when I get home, unless someone beats me to the punch.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Possibly the first *Dogma* movie [Festen](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0154420/) ("The Celebration", "Dogme #1 - Festen") from Denmark, 1998. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Festen). It stars [Ulrich Thomsen](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0860947/?ref_=tt_cl_t1). The director, [Thomas Vinterberg](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0899121/?ref_=tt_ov_dr), also directed Jagden with Mads Mikkelsen. Won many awards, among them the Cannes 1998 Jury Prize.

I saw the movie and so can confirm that it fits your description perfectly and is quite famous, for its kind. The "low quality" is [intentional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dogme_95).

Synopsis (IMDb):

> The Father turns 60. His family, which is a big one of the kind, gathers to celebrate him on a castle. Everybody likes and respects the father deeply...or do they? The youngest son is trying to live up to the father's expectations. He is running a grill-bar in a dirty part of Copenhagen. The oldest son runs a restaurant in France, while the sister is a anthropologist. The older sister has recently committed suicide and the father asks the oldest son to say a few words about her, because he is afraid he will break into tears if he does it himself. The oldest son agrees without argument. Actually he has already written two speeches. A yellow and a green one. By the table, he asks the father to pick a speech. The father chooses green. The oldest son announces that this is the Speech of Truth. Everybody laughs, except for the father who gets a nervous look on his face. For he knows that the oldest son is about to reveal the secret of why the oldest sister killed herself.

Synopsis (Wikipedia):

> At the dinner, the eldest son publicly accuses his father of sexually abusing both him and his twin sister (who has recently killed herself)

Trailer:

Comment: Looks like I did indeed get beaten to the punch, but yeah, this is definitely the right movie.

Comment: Definitely Festen is the correct answer.