# A European (non-English) movie about a birthday celebration that went wrong

Tags: identify-this-movie, drama

I am looking for a European movie that I watched in 2010. I was on a spree of watching classic movies during that time and had amassed a good collection. But I no longer have them and don't remember any of the movies I liked during those days.

### Plot as I remember

The movie revolves around a (Big) Wealthy old man and his family. He was celebrating his (60th?) birthday and all his family members (wife, children, grand children, etc.) were gathered in the family home. The whole movie is shot from this building and its surroundings.

As far as I can remember, this old man has 2 sons and 2 daughters. One of the daughters has taken her life recently in the same building where the celebrations are currently happening. All others, along with their spouses/girlfriends/children were present during the celebration, along with other friends and relatives.

But the event turns sour as one of the sons publicly accuses his father of sexually abusing him and his deceased sister in their growing up days. At first the father denies the accusation and everyone else ignores them. But later, the son takes up the matter again and also accuses the father of causing the death of his sister (who committed suicide in the same building in the near past).

From what I remember, his brothers and sister initially team up with the father and ignore the charges. But  later the suicide note of the deceased sister turns up (can't remember how) that clearly lends evidence to the accusations. In the end, the father accepts the charges and apologises, but his children ignore him and decide to split ways. I remember a scene where his other son (not the accuser) beats his father after the charges were proven correct.

There are some other interesting sub plots that add tension to the events. There is one black guy who is targeted for some racial abuse throughout. I don't remember his relation to the main leads in the movie though.

### Some other points I remember

1. It is a European movie, but not English, Portuguese, or Spanish. I
   watched with the help of English Subtitles.
2. I have a sneaky feeling that it was a Scandinavian movie
3. Probably from 90's, or early 2000
4. It is suited for matured audiences as there are couple of nude
   scenes. The whole story deals with sexual abuse and incest.
5. **Important:** One thing I clearly remember about the movie is that it is shot in a very amateurish way.  It surely wasn't a big budget
   movie. It is as if the entire movie is made using a mobile camera. I
   don't think they used any modern camera equipment.

I don't know whether it is a TV movie or released in theatres. It was surely a feature length movie, not a short film.

That's all I can remember.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sound very much similar to Danish film [Festen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Festen) aka *The Celebration*

> Helge is celebrating his 60th birthday at the family-run hotel. Gathered together amongst many family and friends are his wife Else, eldest son Christian, younger son Michael and his daughter Helene.
>
> Christian's twin sister, Linda, has recently taken her life at the hotel. Later, during dinner, Christian makes a speech to the family in which he accuses Helge of sexually abusing him and Linda as children. There is an initial shocked silence.

Also from [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0154420/):

> At Helge's 60th birthday party, some unpleasant family truths are revealed.

Comment: There was another ID question about this film a few weeks ago, can't find it now though.

Comment: @F1Krazy  it's easy to find, I guess you mean this one : https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82696/what-is-the-name-of-this-danish-award-winning-indie-drama/82699#82699, searched after you comment

Comment: Just a sidenote why this film looks as shot in amateurish way: it is a film of [Dogma 95](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dogme_95#Goals_and_rules) movement (and the very first one).

Comment: So this movie is quite famous it seems. Didn't know that.